# How can I show a specific element that is in the last array?

Tags: node.js

I have this problem in nodejs, I have this array called "trades", when I show with

```
console.info(trades);
```

I see the whole list is inside it

```
[Object: null prototype] {
    id: 83353657,
    orderId: 120372526,
    orderListId: -1,
    price: '0.99990000',
    qty: '10 .10000000 ',
    quoteQty: '10 .09899000 ',
  },
  [Object: null prototype] {
    id: 83357145,
    orderId: 120372986,
    orderListId: -1,
    price: '0.99990000',
    qty: '10 .10000000 ',
    quoteQty: '10 .09899000 ',
  }
```

This list changes over time, and what I need is to bring the last object and what it has inside, to use it on different occasions

For example, show the id of the last element (in this case it would be 83357145), or show the price in a console.info

I am new to Nodejs and I have tried many things but nothing works, surely it is something very simple.

the concrete question is ¿how can I show a specific element that is in the last array?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to the question is that you can use `trades[trades.length - 1]`. 1 is subtracted because array indexes start at 0, so that has to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

After that I just put `var lastTrade = trades[trades.length - 1 ];` and use `lastTrade.price` and `lastTrade.id` to show specific data.